# Python unit testing that a method does not call logging.info with specific messages

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to unit test method that calls `logging.info` three times – first time it's logging local variables for the method, another two times it's logging messages that get triggered in case a certain condition is fulfilled.

In one of my test cases, `logging.info` gets called only once – to log local variables. The other two calls are not supposed to happen. I'm trying to include that in my unit tests but using `unittest.mock.Mock.assert_not_called()` is quite naturally out of question because my `logging.info` gets called once. (However, I can't test `logging.info` message for local variables.)

```py
class Test_create_s3_file(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.LOGGER = logging
        ...

    def test_success_basic(self):
        # Mocks
        self.LOGGER.info = MagicMock()
        ...
        # Calls
        ...
        self.LOGGER.info.assert_not_called()
        # Does not work because it has one call for local variables
```

Comment: Asserting that something is not called is not usually very helpful. Ask yourself if this test you have in mind can ever fail. If not, then it isn't a useful test. In your case, an assertion that a `info()` is called exactly once with the desired parameters will guarantee that it isn't called with the incorrect parameters.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It can fail in case condition that triggers `logging.info` for the other two info messages would be triggered. I see it similarly like if you have `logging.warning` message in your code but your test case is not supposed to trigger warning message, you would include something like `self.LOGGER.warning.assert_not_called()`.

Comment: `assert_not_called()` asserts that a method was never called. You cannot use it for your scenario where a method is called once.

Answer (score 2):

[`.has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) takes a list of [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.call) objects. You can specify exactly which calls a mock is supposed to have this way.

If it is really only loggers that are relevant to you, you can make use of [`assertLogs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs) as well.

Comment: Alternatively `assert_called_once_with()` can be used as a shortcut for a single call.